# Mongodump is not working with new Meteor 1.8

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have just updated Meteor from 1.2 to 1.8 and my application is becoming dead slow.

I want to take my database backup

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
```

But its giving me this error:

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 3001 -d meteor
2018-12-21T16:37:04.269+0500    writing meteor.__kdtimeevents to 
2018-12-21T16:37:04.269+0500    writing meteor.__kdtraces to 
2018-12-21T16:37:04.269+0500    writing meteor.users to 
2018-12-21T16:37:04.270+0500    writing meteor.jobPaymentDetails to 
2018-12-21T16:37:04.270+0500    Failed: error writing data for collection `meteor.__kdtimeevents` to disk: error reading collection: Failed to parse: { find: "__kdtimeevents", skip: 0, snapshot: true, $readPreference: { mode: "secondaryPreferred" }, $db: "meteor" }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.
```

What should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Mongodb version to 4.0 which is the latest version right now fix it for me. Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Looking closely at the error message again, I see this:

```
meteor.__kdtimeevents` to disk: error reading collection: 
Failed to parse: 
  { find: "__kdtimeevents", 
  skip: 0, 
  snapshot: true, 
  $readPreference: { 
    mode: "secondaryPreferred" 
  }, 
  $db: "meteor" }. 

Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.
```

The error may mean that the database structure changed from (whatever mongo version goes with Meteor 1.2), and snapshot is no longer present. The query is also saying `secondaryPreferred` - suggesting that it is assuming a cluster?

Do you have a backup of your data? (I hope so). If you still have an operational version of your system, I would go back to that, and do a mongodump from there.

If it still fails on that collection, you could issue a separate mongodump command on each collection, a little laborious, but perhaps effective.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are storing important data in your development database (if you want to back it up).

If you don't care about the data, you can clear out the databases with a `meteor reset` command.

If you care about the data, you may have a problem. The collection that is failing is a Kadira collection, and won't be important to you. If you keep getting failures, you can do a dump of one collection at a time.

Comment: the data is really important. This only issue I am facing is this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889589/mongodb-4-failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found